# How to get distance between two points from waze

Tags: android, api, maps, waze

i am developing an app in android that must recieve the distance between two points from the user after traveling between them, and that input must be validated, for that i'm thinking of using an API to get the information and make the validations later. I know that it's not the op to ask the user to enter that kind of input, but that's not on me.

For example, if the distance between point A and point B is 13 km according Google Maps Distance Matrix API, i got from the waze api like 18 km. The approach of the app is one about transport so i would prefer to use waze information because it's more accuarate in terms of road traffic.

So, there's any way to take the distance between two points from waze?
more exactly, this one:
[image: valid HTML]

Any help would be appreciated

PD: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain whether you're still looking for an answer, but in theory you could call the Waze routing server in the same way as the [Waze Live Map](https://www.waze.com/livemap) calls it.

The following URL is the request sent to the Waze routing server when I calculate the route between Antwerp and Brussels in Belgium.

```
https://www.waze.com/row-RoutingManager/routingRequest?from=x:4.4024643+y:51.2194475&to=x:4.3517103+y:50.8503396&at=0&returnJSON=true&returnGeometries=false&returnInstructions=false&timeout=60000&nPaths=1&clientVersion=4.0.0&options=AVOID_TRAILS:t,ALLOW_UTURNS:t
```

*Note:* make sure to properly encode this URL when using a script. Those colons and commas might cause issues otherwise.

To calculate the length of a route, you'll need to go through all the traversed road segments and make a sum of the `length` fields (expressed in metres, if I'm not mistaken).

Do note that the results will differ from time to time as Waze includes historical traffic data in its results and will decide to make detours, which may not be wanted for your use case.

I would also strongly suggest to look into the legal status of doing this, though I suspect it won't be a big issue if you're not using this data to make a competing service or 'forget' to mention you're using Waze data to calculate things.

Comment: i found another approach to achieve this, but i really wanted to know how to do this, in the next week (when i have some time) i will test it, and if it works i'll give you the accepted answer :)
Thanks a lot!